# How to calculate time difference with schedule working b/w two time stamps?

Tags: php, mysql, time

Here is the scenario that i have a table of task `start_time` and `end_time` like this, **On start** method i note `start_time` and **On pause/in review/done** i note the `end_time` here is my **table**

```
ID    |    task_id       |    start_time      |     end_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1             1           2017-03-02 06:27:28   2017-03-12 10:43:37
2             5           2017-03-02 07:16:05          NULL//in progress no end time
```

for example there are **shifting hours** from **6** to **10** and **working days** in week i want to calculate exact time during **shifting hours in working days**. I have searched a lot to find the answer please help me with a proper calculation method.

Note: where `end_time` is **NULL** there i use `date()` means current date

Comment: Are you aware that the server time is constant, and based upon GMT?  Regardless of the client side, the server time never changes.  Is your question about how to display the time to the User properly?

Comment: it's like monitoring on basis of server time suppose i set working hour as server time to my time conversion then, i want to calculate number of minutes which are elapsed during working shift, in working days

Comment: Maybe you should show us what your desired result is. From what you say it's very straightforward. There are plenty of MySQL functions to do 'math' on date/time columns.

Comment: i have tried strtotime(end_time) - strtotime(start_date) this gives a complete difference but i want only time elapsed in given shifting hours and also factor includes that that days should be working day of week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762442)

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2017-03-02 06:27:28');
if($datetime1->format("D")!="Sun" && $datetime1->format("D")!="Sat")
{
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-03-12 10:43:37');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%s');
}
```

Comment: I love it.............. you are so smart dear, $interval->format('%d %H:%I:%s'); will be more helpful please edit and update code

Comment: you answer was so helpful