# How to convert the time gmt format?

Tags: php, mysql, time

Here i have a date entry as by default `mysql`

**Input:** `'2017-03-9 06:27:28'`

**Output:** `'2017-03-9 11:27:28'`

i want to convert this time using `php` in GMT +5 format please help me the function to solve this

Comment: Your date string looks broken.  Can you at least show us what output you want?

Comment: please check this @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Assuming you're storing your dates in GMT in the database, and also assuming you have a date type, would you find it acceptable to just add 5 hours in query itself?

Comment: yes you are right but data is to be used in different countries so by default i have saved GMT 0 , i want to fetch and convert it with different regions on php level

Comment: please @TimBiegeleisen try in php i am waiting for your answer

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-amount-of-hours-to-date

Comment: thanks @TimBiegeleisen this is help full using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2017-03-9 06:27:28 +10 hours'))` your suggestion was helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139209/discussion-between-mudassar-zahid-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/762426)

```
$string=strtotime("2017-03-9 06:27:28"); //converting time to timestamp
$timestamp=strtotime("+5 hours",$string);//added zone time
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp); //displaying new time
```

Comment: @MudassarZahid Welcome... :)

Comment: can you please review my yesterday question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047820/how-to-calculate-time-difference-with-schedule-working-b-w-two-time-stamps

Comment: @MudassarZahid do you want to get time difference between `start_time` and `end_time`

Comment: yes but want to skip other hours then working hours, and weekend days